# So I am having trouble with sfml because it wont play sound with sf::music

Tags: c++, sfml

so I am having a problem with sfml. it compiles just fine but one it is ran it doesn't play any sound.

```
sf::Music music;
if (!music.openFromFile("Title_screen_music.ogg"))
    return -1; // error
music.play();
```

Comment: Where si the music file relative to the directory you ran the program from? Is it the same directory?

Comment: SFML typically reports file errors to the standard error stream. Does anything get printed to the command line? And what happens after this code? Do you pause and give the sound time to play or do you immediately return?

Comment: No, nothing gets printed to the command line. Since it closes immediately I dont have ti give it time,

Comment: You're not giving the sound any time to play. It plays in a separate thread and is stopped when it is destroyed, which happens if you return immediately from the function. If you make a call to `sf::sleep(sf::seconds(5.0f));` after calling `play()`, do you hear anything? You might need to `#include <SFML/System.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

`sf::Music` plays in a separate thread, and will play until it is stopped, such as by calling `stop` or if the `sf::Music` is destroyed (for example, if it is a local variable and its function returns). To hear the music, you need to keep the `sf::Music` object alive while you wait and actually give it time to play. In a game, you would typically store the `sf::Music` object somewhere while you continuously handle user input, advance the game simulation, and render the visuals. For test purposes, it suffices to simply block for a few seconds and do nothing:

```
bool playMusicForFiveSeconds(){
    sf::Music music;
    if (!music.openFromFile("Title_screen_music.ogg"))
        return false;
    music.play();
    sf::sleep(sf::seconds(5.0f));
    return true;
    // since music is a local variable, it is destroyed here (thus stopping playback)
}
```

Curiously, it's not currently documented that the destructor of `sf::Music` actually stops playback, but looking at the source code, all the destructor does is call `stop();`, which makes sense from an RAII perspective.